# How do you write Ranged Inequality Constraint in Pyomo

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

**I'm new to Pyomo and I need help writing this equation in Pyomo.**

I'm trying to write a (ranged inequality) constraint equation in Pyomo.

Here is the equation:

[image]

So far I wrote these 2 versions:

Version 1: Not sure if this correct

```
model.amount_of_energy_con = pe.ConstraintList()
for t in model.time:
    lhs = 0
    rhs = sum(model.c_ratings[s] * model.boat_capacity * model.charging[b, t, s] * model.boats_availability[b][t] for b in model.boats for s in model.chargers)
    body = sum(model.charge_energy[b, t, s] for b in model.boats for s in model.chargers)
    model.amount_of_energy_con.add(lhs <= body)
    model.amount_of_energy_con.add(body <= rhs)
```

Version 2: I think this is not correct

```
model.amount_of_energy_con = pe.ConstraintList()
for t in model.time:
    lhs = 0
    rhs = sum(model.c_ratings[s] * model.boat_capacity * model.charging[b, t, s] * model.boats_availability[b][t] for b in model.boats for s in model.chargers)
    body = sum(model.charge_energy[b, t, s] for b in model.boats for s in model.chargers)
    #model.amount_of_energy_con.add(expr=pe.inequality(lhs, body, rhs))
    model.amount_of_energy_con.add(lhs, body, rhs)
```

Note:

1. All the subscripts in the equation are elements of 3 different sets. s Elements of Set S (model.chargers), b Elements of Set B (model.boats), t Elements of Set T (model.time).
2. C-rate, Availability, Battery capacity are given parameters while E and Charging are Variables in Pyomo.

Please, let me know what you think and how to write it in Pyomo. Generally if there is something you think I'm doing wrong, please me know and also if you need my full code, data and further explanation let me know as well.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: your 2nd version looks fine w/ caveat that I would avoid ranged inequalities and just break it into 2 inequalities, or more succinctly, just put a lower bound of 0 on `E` when you declare it.  I'm not sure, but I seem to recall there are a few quirks to the ranged inequalities, and under the hood, it is just breaking it into 2 for you anyhow.  Is something not working with the second?  When you `pprint()` the model, does it look accurate?

Comment: Thank you @AirSquid as suggested I break the range inequality in version 1 & I got these: 

```amount_of_energy_con_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :   48 : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}

amount_of_energy_con : Size=48, Index=amount_of_energy_con_index, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body```    
Not sure I understand with ```pprint() ```

Comment: Also, I'm suspecting I have something else going wrong in my code. 

Let me see If I can upload my full code with data.

Comment: that is the index over which it is being called, but not the product of the constraint production.  Is there more?  You should edit your post above to include error messages and output (easier to read) rather than stuff a comment.  ;)

Comment: I tried to run your code, but there are multiple errors...  It is customary to include a minimally reproducible example.  If you can do that, I (or somebody else) can help.  minimal implies just enough data to make it run, so cut it down to like 3 time periods and 1 or 2 boats.  Right now it is way too big to troubleshoot.  Then include the data in the code, and run it -- just as posted -- on your machine and ensure there are no syntax errors and it produces the error or issue that you want help with.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion @AirSquid. 

I will try to run it with minimal data. 

Between, when I run the code, I wasn't getting any error except that part (some of variables on) the constraint were Infeasible so my results (both ```model.number_of_FC_chargers``` and ```model.number_of_SC_chargers``` was 0.0 ). Means I was doing something wrong. 

I will try to run it minimally and update here if something positive. 

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
model.amount_of_energy_con = pe.ConstraintList()
    for t in model.time:
        for b in model.boats:
            for s in model.chargers:
                lhs = model.charge_energy[b, t, s]
                rhs = model.c_rating[s] * model.boat_battery_capacity * boats_availability[b, t] * model.charging[b, t, s]
                model.amount_of_energy_con.add(expr= (lhs <= rhs))
```

The problem with those previous versions I posted above in the question are:

1. The sum() function/ method will do sum of the variables and parameters which is not what I want because the equation doesn't have summation. The 2 versions above will work if we are trying to do summation of the variables on the right and left hand side separately.
2. The 0 in the range inequalities/ left hand side was covered using the "within parameter" when writing the charge_energy variable as follows `model.charge_energy = pe.Var(model.boats, model.time, model.chargers, within=pe.NonNegativeReals)`.

Thank you.